# Animated mix shader doesn´t work

Tags: rendering

I created a video in Blender 2.8 today.
Unfortunately, the text I blend in via an animated factor in a mix shader, does not show up in the render preview (shift+z).

Comment: Dies ist eine Englisch sprachige Seite. Mit Deutsch kommst Du hier nicht weit! There is no Blender 2.9 yet. Also you should provide some screenshots or the blend file if you can. You didnt even ask a proper question. One question mark is enough, we are not 4chan. Does it render properly when hitting F12?

Comment: yeah, I think we need more information.  Screenshots would be nice?